# AWS CodeDeploy error with bundler: opt/codedeploy-agent/Gemfile not found

Tags: aws-code-deploy

when I call bundle install as a AfterInstall hook, I get the error: "opt/codedeploy-agent/Gemfile not found"

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this.

I found the answer at https://medium.com/@davedash/bundler-and-amazon-codedeploy-afc684087b73, which is adding `unset BUNDLE_GEMFILE` at the top of your script.

I don't know why CodeDeploy is setting this ENV variable.